# Getting error Access Denied while adding linked account on razorpay using rest call on postman

Tags: postman, backend, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am trying to create a linked account on razor pay using postman but getting error response as follow:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BAD_REQUEST_ERROR",
        "description": "Access Denied",
        "source": "NA",
        "step": "NA",
        "reason": "NA",
        "metadata": {}
    }
}
```

At first I thought, maybe I am sending auth parameter wrong. But I am able to create orders by sending the auth in the same manner. I tried both by passing directly basic auth in header section and by adding key and secret in authorization section as Basic auth, both are working while creating order but none in case of adding linked account.

Here is the endpoint - https://api.razorpay.com/v2/accounts

I can confirm that i am providing right Content-type and Authorization,as I have passed same data for creating order.

This is the body (I suppose the error is not related to the body, because nothing is mentioned in error except Access Denied) -

```
{
   "email":"any.mail@mailinator.com",
   "phone":"9999990000",
   "type":"route",
   "reference_id":"1241424",
   "legal_business_name":"anyuser",
   "business_type":"partnership",
   "contact_name":"User",
   "profile":{
      "category":"healthcare",
      "subcategory":"clinic",
      "addresses":{
         "registered":{
            "street1":"507, Koramangala 1st block",
            "street2":"MG Road",
            "city":"Bengaluru",
            "state":"KARNATAKA",
            "postal_code":"560034",
            "country":"IN"
         }
      }
   },
   "legal_info":{
      "pan":"AAACL1254D",
      "gst":"18AAACU9603R1ZZ"
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing reference_id, i was also getting same which got resolved after this

Comment: Need your help again!!! Please answer this one if possible - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77820243

Comment: Did you tried manually clicking terms and conditions in account and submitting, this may make your account active, then you can just validate for terms and conditions