# In razorpay, I am getting linked account status as "-" when created from API

Tags: integration, payment-gateway, razorpay

Anyone know why account status is showing as "-". I created a linked account using APIs and did not faced any issue. I did all 4 steps as mentioned in their docs- create linked account, add stakeholder, Request a Product Configuration, Update a Product Configuration and after updating all the requirements were solved and the requirement list is coming empty now.

[image]

But when checking on UI side, I am getting account status as -, any idea why?

One thing, I have entered false details in the whole process, as I am still testing and developing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Account status by given API : https://api.razorpay.com/v2/accounts/<account_id_acc_nsuh>/products/<acc_prd_yourproductid>

This will give you correct response.

or for testing go for beta API of Razor Pay.

Comment: The following endpoint returns activation_status as under_review, even though the details provided are all correct, and the status is under review for more then 2-3 weeks, and when done through ui/dashboard even the false details show as activated account, any idea why??